# Can every finitely generated module be written as a sum of simple modules?

Tags: modules, cyclic-decomposition

Let $R$ be a ring with unity. Take for granted that an $R$-module $M$ is simple if and only if it is cyclic, and that if $m \in M$ then $Rm$ is a submodule of $M$.

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and suppose $N=\{m_1, \ldots ,m_k \}$ generates $M$. Then each $Rm_i$ is a simple module, and since $span(N)=M$, it follows that $$Rm_1 \oplus  \ldots \oplus Rm_k=M ,$$
and the result is proven.

Is the above true?

Answer (score 1):

> Take for granted that an $R$-module $M$ is simple if and only if it is cyclic,

At this point, you have implicitly assumed $R$ is a division ring, so every $R$ module is a sum of simple modules (copies of $R$).

> since $span(N)=M$, it follows that $$Rm_1 \oplus  \ldots \oplus R_k=m ,$$

This assumes that your generating set is “a basis” which is true when $R$ is a Division ring if you additionally assume it is a minimal generating set.

So the result is true, but you haven’t established it.

Comment: Why do I need to assume that $R$ is a division ring if I don't use that in the proof? And is assuming that $M$ is torsion-free enough $Rm_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus Rm_k = M$ to hold?

Comment: @MonzurRahman You *do* use it to conclude such a thing as a basis exists. That is not possible in all commutative rings, even.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the proof of 'A module is simple if and only if it's cyclic.' Surely we don't need $R$ to be a division ring for that to hold? And if I add the assumption that $M$ is torsion-free, is that enough?

Comment: @MonzurRahman With your hypothesis: $R$ itself is cyclic, therefore simple. A ring which is a simple right module over itself is necessarily a division ring.  Your assumption is very restrictive.